# UITabBarController tab images and titles are not set until I tap them

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have set the properties `title`, `image` and `selected-image` of each of my UIViewControllers in their `viewDidLoad:` method. These View Controllers are in a UITabBarController, and according to the documentation provided, if you set these three properties, the UITabBarController will automatically display them.

```
[self setTitle: @"title"];
[self.tabBarItem setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[self.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-selected.png"]];
```

But the problem is that the View Controllers are not instantiated until the user taps the corresponding tab in the UITabBar, so until the moment that the tabs are not pressed, neither the images or the title are shown.

Is there any **clean and OOP** way to make the UITabBarController refresh and pull the data from its View Controllers? What's the point of having a `title`, `image` and `selected-image` property if you have to manually tell the UITabBarController which is which?

Comment: I just implemented the most sketchy unclean solution there is: I subclassed the UITabBarController and made it loop through all its View Controllers and then returning to the first one. Please help me to find another way!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is not called until the view actually needs to be loaded for the first time, which in this case is when you switch to the ViewController's tab.

Try setting these properties in the ViewController's designated initializer instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using storyboard you should use awakeFromNib instead. Like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setTitle:@"title"];
    [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [self.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-selected.png"]];
}
```